# Sticky user input and button next to each other css

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I'm trying to make a user input and a button appear next to one another. And make them sticky, so as you scroll they remain on the screen at the top. I've tried the float: left method and display:inline-block. I can't seem to work out how to do it. Code below

```
<div id="user-input-and-button">
    <input id="user-input" />     
    <button id="send-button" onClick={writeUserData}>send</button> }
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
#user-input{
  width: 70%;
float:left;
height:auto;
padding: 12px 20px;
border: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
border-radius: 40px;
font-size: calc(5px + 4vmin);
position:fixed;

}


#send-button{
float:left;
width: 7%;
height:auto;
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  position:fixed;

}
```

And:

```
#user-input{
  width: 70%;
height:auto;
padding: 12px 20px;
border: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
border-radius: 40px;
font-size: calc(5px + 4vmin);
position:fixed;
display:inline-block;
}


#send-button{
width: 7%;
height:auto;
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  position:fixed;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.group{
position:fixed;
top:0;
background:gray;
padding:10px;
width:100%;
}
.mt{
margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="user-input-and-button" class="group">
      <input id="user-input" />     
     <button id="send-button" onClick={writeUserData}>send</button>
</div>
<div class="mt">
<p>
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</p>
<p>
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</p>
<p>
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</p>
<p>
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</p>
</div>
```

Run the above code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can make them side by side with [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex). As for sticking, use [`position: sticky`](https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46).

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#user-input-and-button {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#user-input {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
  border-radius: 40px;
  font-size: calc(5px + 4vmin);
}

#send-button {
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="user-input-and-button">
  <input id="user-input"/>
  <button id="send-button"/>
</div>
```